# How to use double click instead of one click in the following codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I give command the following codes to work when user double clicks not one click?

```
$(function () { 
       $(".SpanHoma").on("click", function () {
          $(this).find(".RitualsGroup").toggle(); // this will check which one is clicked currently
       }); 
    });
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "SpanHoma">
  <span>A</span>
  <div class= "RitualsGroup" style = "display:none;">
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
   </div>
</div>

<div class= "SpanHoma">
  <span>B</span>
  <div class= "RitualsGroup" style = "display:none;">
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated language tags. This is a quick way towards getting a question down-voted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`dblclick`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) instead of `click`:

> The `dblclick` event fires when a pointing device button (such as a mouse's primary button) is double-clicked; that is, when it's rapidly clicked twice on a single element within a very short span of time.

```js
$(function () { 
  $(".SpanHoma").on("dblclick", function () {
    $(this).find(".RitualsGroup").toggle(); // this will check which one is clicked currently
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "SpanHoma">
  <span>A</span>
  <div class= "RitualsGroup" style = "display:none;">
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
   </div>
</div>

<div class= "SpanHoma">
  <span>B</span>
  <div class= "RitualsGroup" style = "display:none;">
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SchadrackRurangwa, you are most welcome:)